# Connection of c++ with mysql in Linux

Tags: c++, mysql, linux

I am learning to work with mysql and c++ in ubuntu os. There are several tutorials on how to interface mysql with c++ in visual studio or in windows, but not one for Linux. Mysql website also does not describe properly on this.
Can anyone suggest me a link to tutorial, book or any thing that gives information an how to interface c++ with mysql in Linux. My database is in linux machine itself.
Thanks for the great help.

Comment: I found this by searching for 'MySQL c++ programming' - [the official developer documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/index.html).

Comment: I am talking about with out using ide. I want to connect by vi editor.

Comment: The process is the same regardless of whether you use an IDE or a text editor. The only difference is that you'll need to pass the library in to the linker manually when you compile (although you really should be using automatic build tools or at least a Makefile). If @yanivx's answer worked for you, you should mark it as the "accepted answer" by clicking on the tick on the left side so it turns green.

Answer (score 1):

Mysql is a database, and to gain access to the data within C++ you will need to be able to “talk” to the database via queries (just like on the mysql command line interface e.g. select * from tablename), the connection process is very similar to the command line interface you will need to supply connection details as in hostname (localhost normally), username, password, database to use and also there are other details that you can pass e.g port number more information can be gained from the MYSQL API pages.

This link has a good example

[Connect mysql in c++ for unix](http://www.codingfriends.com/index.php/2010/02/17/mysql-connection-example/comment-page-1/)